# How to give my list of DIV elements a checkbox functionality?

Tags: jquery, css, spring-mvc

I have a simle HTML page which displays a list. Each item on the list is a div element (round-corner box) that contains some data and a checkbox. 
Now I'm trying to give the div the functionality of the checkbox, meanning when the user will click the div I want it to change color (or display an image of a V) and when the user submits the page I want all the item ids that were checked to be sent.
Here is a snipet of the HTML:

```
<!-- item only list -->     
<div class="container">
  <ul class="plainList">
    <c:forEach items="${itemsFrom.itemsOnly}" var="item" varStatus="status">            
      <li>
        <div class="inner">
          <img src="resources/images/${item.id}.png">           
          <ul class="plainList">             
            <li><h4>${item.title} &trade;</h4></li>              
            <li><h5>${item.description}</h5></li>            
          </ul>            
          <input style="float: right;" type="checkbox" name="itemIds" value="${item.id}" />           
          <div style="clear: both"></div>           
        </div>           
      </li>         
    </c:forEach>      
  </ul>     
</div>
```

Can anyone help me start: JQuery? CSS?. any simple examples?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help you. I don't know what divs you want to have this functionality, but I would suggest grouping them.

```
$(".inner").click(function(){
   $(this).css("background-color", "red");
})
```

Comment: OK. that works fine. can you help me with the second part:  returning the checked Ids to the server, how can I retrieve the `${item.id}` from each selected element in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) ? 
There are multiple ways to achieve your goal but for me, the more efficient is to use jQuery and the event `click`.
In your example, you've to bind the event `click` on each div which have the class `inner`. 
The syntax is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inner").click(function(){
        //Do some stuff
    });
});
```

In a second part, jQuery include the function `.css()` which allows you to set css-property of the matched element.
For example, if you want to change the background-image of your div :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inner").click(function(){
        $(this).css("background-image","url(path/to/your/image)");
    });
});
```

You'll understand that this snippet of code will not reproduce the "checkbox functionnality", but just change the background of your `div` once.
You should take a look at the jQuery event `.toggle()`.

To help you, this is the syntax to do what you want :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".inner").toggle(
            function(){
                $(this).css("background-image","url(path/to/your/image1)");    
            },
            function(){
                $(this).css("background-image","url(path/to/your/image2)");
            }
        );

    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. the examples were helpful and I got my items to change background. I'm still stuck with returning the checked Ids to the server, how can I retrieve the `${item.id}` from each selected element in the list?

Comment: You have to set an attribute to the `<div>` element, for example (if `${item.id}` are uniques) : `<div id="${item.id}" class="inner">`, then in your `toggle` or `click` function event, which is initialized by the selector `$(".inner")` (your item's div), you'll retrieve the `${item.id}` by `this.id` or `$(this).attr("id")`.

Comment: OK. So I retrieve the Ids, push them into an array.  A new problem: up until now when the user clicked the "Submit" button all data was sent automatically to the server (the checked checkboxs as an array and also start/end time). Now I get: "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect", how do I return the array to the server? do I need to overwrite the onClick of my button?